# Jest mock an object

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I need to mock an object, `config.js`, rather than mocking a function as normal.  I have -

```
//config.js . 
export default {
   foo: 'bar'
}
```

I have tried -

```
import config from './config';
jest.mock('./config');
config.mockReturnValue({
   foo: 'zed'
})
```

also -

```
import config from './config';
jest.mock('./config');
config.mockImplentation(() => ({
   foo: 'zed'
}));
```

But its not mocking anything, and I am getting the config file as normal.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this work for you?


`jest.mock('./config', () => ({ foo: 'zed' }));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a solution for this now. You can use:

```
jest.replaceProperty(config, 'foo', 'zed');
```

More info: [Jest Documentation - jest.replaceProperty](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestreplacepropertyobject-propertykey-value)

Answer (score 28):

The second parameter of `jest.mock` accepts a factory which you can use to return the *object* you want to mock:

```
jest.mock('./config', () => ({ foo: 'zed' }))
```

or you can modify the object:

```
import config from './config';
config.foo = 'zed'
```

The problem with your approach is that it would only work for modules that return functions.

[Jest Documentation - jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options)

Comment: Your answer is save my days, turns out it is very simple, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

```
jest.spyOn(config, 'foo', 'get').mockReturnValue('zed');
                           ↑↑↑
```

Prefer `spyOn()` over `mock()` as it can be scoped to the test while mock is hoisted.

Source: https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/issues/3884#issuecomment-1664286224